# Can someone show me more example where particle と is used the way it is in this sentence

Tags: particle-と

食べ物や化粧品など免税の品物をウェブサイトで予約するとQRコードが出ます Link to the article https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10013941291000/k10013941291000.html

Comment: You can search conditional と online. https://www.japanesegrammar.com.au/joining-sentences/conditional-sentences-and/conditional-when /  https://guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals / https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/09/03/jlptn4-grammar-to/

Comment: Requesting examples from the community is off-topic in this community.  Instead, please indicate your understanding of the grammar in question, and perhaps provide your own examples that you think match the usage to supplement your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It's a link between cause and effect.

ボタンを押すとベルがなる

からかうと泣く

もらうと喜ぶ